# How to implement my login form in popup and after successful login close the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to implement my login form in a popup.
When i click on login button a popup should open with having fields username and password and should close after the successful login

Here my code i want this to open up in pop up

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>XXXXXXXXXXX - Login</title>

</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>XXXXXXXX</h1>
    <div id="error">${error}</div>
    <form name="login" action='j_spring_security_check'
        method="post">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' maxlength="50" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' maxlength="20" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="submit" type="submit"></td>
                <td><input name="reset" type="reset"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <a href="register/normal">Register</a>
     &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <a href="forgotpassword">Forgot Password</a>
     <br/>
     <br/>
    <form action='j_spring_openid_security_check' method="post">
        <input name="openid_identifier" type="hidden"
            value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" /> <input
            type="submit" value="SignIn with Google" />
    </form>
     &nbsp; 
    <form action='j_spring_openid_security_check' method="post">
        <input name="openid_identifier" type="hidden"
            value="https://me.yahoo.com/user" /> <input type="submit"
            value="SignIn with Yahoo" />
    </form>
     &nbsp; 
    <form id="fb_signin" action="signin/facebook" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="publish_stream,offline_access" />
        <button type="submit">SignIn with facebook</button>
    </form>
    &nbsp;
    <form id="tw_signin" action="signin/twitter" method="POST">
        <button type="submit">SignIn with twitter</button>
    </form>
    &nbsp;
    <form id="ln_signin" action="signin/linkedin" method="POST">

        <button type="submit">SignIn with Linkedin</button>
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: Show your code that you tried

Comment: This may be helpful [Modals](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) You can customise them easily

Comment: @VickyGonsalves [Don't ask for efforts, ask for minimal understanding instead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: Sir you can look at the above code i cant do this with simple dialog box i want the default functionality of browser for pop up as facebook have

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ 
May be its help you.

Comment: @Ashish Do you want it to load on page startup?

Comment: No sir i want simply this page should come on as i will click on login button and all the above functionality like sign in facebook and all should work in that popup but as on successful login i should come to my parent window by closing that popup

Comment: Why you need to close the popup, if the page is redirecting to another page?

Comment: @Surjith Sir it is my requirement that i dont want to take the user away from my site to another page like fb login page and other so i want to do this in pop up

Comment: Please put your code in http://jsfiddle.net So that we can understand better